# Weak WiFi signal and Macbook Pro Antennae Cable - LCD screen replacement

Tags: macbook-pro, display, wifi, screen

I'm using a Macbook Pro Mid-2015, 15-inch laptop. I successfully replaced my Macbook's broken LCD screen, and the screen and camera are all working fine. However, when I got to the three antennae cables that are connected to the WiFi card, I was having a hard time getting them to go inside their connecting spots. Two of them came easily onto their spots, but the longest one is just not coming to the right angle to be sticked in. I tried sticking it in, and closed the Macbook Lid and turned the power on. Consequently, I think it's detached as I'm typing this, and I see my WiFi signal being diminished (4 WiFi bars instead of 5).

Is there any way that I can get this antennae cable to be held in its place? Do I really need to buy another LCD screen to correct this problem?

Any input to help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you actually experiencing any *real life* internet slow downs? I mean, after all 4/5 bars is still pretty strong and could easily due to something completely different.

Comment: Yes. At times, it drops to 2 or 3 WiFi bars, or the WiFi completely failing to work. At other times, the WiFi is at 5 bars, and the only reason I can think of that is that the antennae cable that is detached starts moving closer to its designated place, though I could be wrong.